# Why can i RDP into my Pi4 with public adress while i havent forwarded 3389 on my router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, remote-desktop

I fowarded 3389 on my router to my pi a while ago. But now im running a vpn on the pi and use this instead to connect. So why can i still use my public adress and connect while i unforwarded the port from the router ? does the client can find the pi by himself. I tried blocking the port and it still works ...

Comment: That's weird, you should factory reset the router. This is obviously a bug. See if the manufacturer has a patched newer firmware to flash on it.

Comment: Did you set up a DMZ to point to your Pi on your router? That would do it.

Comment: Maybe there is registry configuration that make remote connection use other port number instead of 3389. You can use tool "Network Monitor" to collect the network trace during RDP and check what port it is using. Tool download link  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865

Answer (score 0):

I did a factory reset and luckily it started working again. I never would have though a router could bug like that. Thanks for your answers.